# Point selection criterion in `Method->RandomSearch`

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

In `NonlinearModelFit` one can specify `Method->{"NMinimize", Method->"RandomSearch"}` while giving a guess for the fit parameters not as a range like `{param, pstart, pend}` but rather `{parap, pguess}`. In this last case how does mathematica select the random starting points upon which to run `FindMinimum`?

Does in the range case it just throw random numbers in that range of values?

Comment: You mean `NMinimize` right? Have you tried looking in the `NMinimize` documentation?

Comment: @sebhofer I read `Numerical Nonlinear Global Optimization` tutorial, but that particular point was not expounded.

Comment: I believe linear programming is used to handle linear but non-rectangular constraints (rectangular being of the form `a<=x<=b`). LP is strictly for constraint satisfaction, not used on the objective.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I still don't quite understand how it does it. My fit is highly nonlinear.

Comment: Finding initial points subject to some set of linear inequalities can be done by linear programming. The objective function need not be linear, and it is not considered in the phase of finding initial points.